# Flutter Bluetooth External Barcode Scanner

Tags: android, ios, flutter, barcode

I need to use an external barcode scanner which is connected via Bluetooth to my device (it is recognized as a keyboard). It works well and I can get the content of a barcode inside a TextField.

The problem is that I need to set the focus to the TextField in order to get the content of the barcode... Is there a way for the current screen to listen to the keyboard event that way I could get the data without wasting time selecting the TextField?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late but you can set the TextField autofocus prop to true.

```
TextField(
  autofocus:true,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example code for RawKeyboardListener:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      static const String _title = 'RawKeyboardListener';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: _title,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
            body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
    }
    
    class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
      final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
    
      String _controller = '';
    
      String? _message;
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _focusNode.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
        final TextTheme textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: DefaultTextStyle(
            style: textTheme.bodyText1!,
            child: RawKeyboardListener(
              focusNode: _focusNode,
              onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
                if (event is RawKeyDownEvent) {
                  if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
                    print('ENTER');
                    setState(() {
                      _message = _controller;
                      _controller = '';
                    });
                  } else {
                    print(
                        '_handleKeyEvent Event data keyLabel ${event.data.keyLabel}');
                    _controller += event.data.keyLabel;
                  }
    
                  print('controller: $_controller');
                }
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    _message ?? 'Press a key',
                  ),
                  Text(
                    '${_message?.length}',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

You can use TextEditingController for TextFormField