# NETUM barcode scanner writes on chrome the barcode how to read it inside my application in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I am writing an application that scans medical data barcode, to make the process quick , we have bought the scanner hardware NETUM, that scans the barcode and writes it in chrome by default, it uses keyboard of the device. I want to catch this data in my android application.
Any help please.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555472/flutter-bluetooth-external-barcode-scanner

Comment: Yes it does :) merci